# Finding all sequences of A, B such that have a specified number of each element

Tags: python, python-itertools

For example, given the two letters A and B, I'd like to generate all strings of length n that have x A's and y B's.

I'd like this to be done efficiently. One way that I've considered is to build a length x list of A's, and then insert y B's into the list every possible way. But insertion into a python list is linear, so this method would suck as the list gets big.

PERFORMANCE GOAL (this may be unreasonable, but it *is* my hope): Generate all strings of length 20 with equal numbers of A and B in time less than a minute.

EDIT: Using permutations('A' * x, 'B' * y) has been suggested. While not a bad idea, it's wasting a lot. If x = y = 4, you'd generate the string 'AAAABBBB' many times. Is there a better way that might generate each string only once? I've tried code to the effect of set(permutations('A' * x, 'B' * y)) and it is too slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your concerns with the performance, here is an actual generator implementation of your idea (without `insert`). It finds the positions for `B` and fill the list accordingly.

```
import itertools

def make_sequences(num_a, num_b):
    b_locations = range(num_a+1)
    for b_comb in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(b_locations, num_b):
        result = []
        result_a = 0
        for b_position in b_comb:
            while b_position > result_a:
                result.append('A')
                result_a += 1
            result.append('B')
        while result_a < num_a:
            result.append('A')
            result_a += 1
        yield ''.join(result)
```

It does perform better. Comparing with the [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422959/843822)'s solution (naming it `make_sequences2`):

```
In : %timeit list(make_sequences(4,4))
10000 loops, best of 3: 145 us per loop

In : %timeit make_sequences2(4,4)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.08 ms per loop
```

**Edit**

A generalized version:

```
import itertools

def insert_letters(sequence, rest):
    if not rest:
        yield sequence
    else:
        letter, number = rest[0]
        rest = rest[1:]
        possible_locations = range(len(sequence)+1)
        for locations in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(possible_locations, number):
            result = []
            count = 0
            temp_sequence = sequence
            for location in locations:
                while location > count:
                    result.append(temp_sequence[0])
                    temp_sequence = temp_sequence[1:]
                    count += 1
                result.append(letter)
            if temp_sequence:
                result.append(temp_sequence)
            for item in insert_letters(''.join(result), rest):
                yield item

def generate_sequences(*args):
    '''
    arguments : squence of (letter, number) tuples
    '''
    (letter, number), rest = args[0], args[1:]
    for sequence in insert_letters(letter*number, rest):
        yield sequence
```

Usage:

```
for seq in generate_sequences(('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('C', 1)):
    print seq

# Outputs
# 
# CBAA
# BCAA
# BACA
# BAAC
# CABA
# ACBA
# ABCA
# ABAC
# CAAB
# ACAB
# AACB
# AABC
```

Comment: Question! Any idea how to generalize this to multiple letters? For example, what if we wanted all strings of A, B, and C with x A's, y B's and d C's?

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to do this would be the following:

```
import itertools

def make_sequences(x, y):
    return set(itertools.permutations("A" * x + "B" * y))
```

The `itertools.permutations()` function doesn't take into account the repeated elements in the input list. It ends up generating permutations that are duplicates of previously generated permutations. So using the `set()` constructor removes the duplicate elements in the result.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I made a relevant EDIT to the question.

Comment: Presumably you're going to actually *do* something with these results. Before dismissing such a solution, I would strongly suggest measuring the performance of your completed code and concentrate on the part that takes the greatest amount of time. I suspect you will find that generating permutations won't be it.

Comment: That's a fair concern, but I'm afraid that it _is_ the bottleneck. I'm using these sequences to generate all random walks in a square grid that end up back at the origin. But for x = y = 6, the above code takes over a minute to run. This corresponds to random walks of length 12. I'd like to get to 20 at least.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the idea (I've included every step so you can see what's going on):

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 3
>>> lst_a = ['A'] * x
>>> lst_b = ['B'] * y
>>> print lst_a, lst_b
['A', 'A'] ['B', 'B', 'B']
>>> lst_a.extend(lst_b)
>>> lst_a
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
>>> print list(itertools.permutations(lst_a))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that as strings are iterables, you can just forget the lists and work directly on the strings.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I made a relevant EDIT to the question.